# polar coordinates of a point are given $(4,-180^{\circ})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The Polar coordinates of a point are given $(4,-180^{\circ})$. Find the rectangular coordinates of the point.

Comment: Use the definition of polar coordinates. Hint: Use trigonometry

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**
\begin{align}
x&=r\cos\theta\\
y&=r\sin\theta\\
r^2&=x^2+y^2
\end{align}